# How do I implement implicit identity error in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit

I recently noticed a difficulty I'm having with Qiskit Aer. I want to simulate a quantum circuit where idling qubits suffer some noise. The problem is that AerSimulator doesn't implement noise on idling qubits, except where an identity gate is explicitly defined.

For example:

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.h(0)
circ.h(0)
circ.h(0)
circ.h(0)
circ.save_density_matrix()
print(circ)
```

We'd expect that the second qubit would suffer idling noise since it's not being acted on for 4 time steps. This is not the observed behaviour.

```
p_id = 1.0
noise = NoiseModel()
error_id = depolarizing_error(p_id, 1)
noise.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_id, "id")

sim_wnoise = AerSimulator(noise_model=noise)
result = sim_wnoise.run(circ).result()
print(result.data(0)['density_matrix'])
```

```
>> DensityMatrix([[1.+0.0000000e+00j, 0.-1.2246468e-16j, 0.+0.0000000e+00j,
                0.+0.0000000e+00j],
               [0.+1.2246468e-16j, 0.+0.0000000e+00j, 0.+0.0000000e+00j,
                0.+0.0000000e+00j],
               [0.+0.0000000e+00j, 0.+0.0000000e+00j, 0.+0.0000000e+00j,
                0.+0.0000000e+00j],
               [0.+0.0000000e+00j, 0.+0.0000000e+00j, 0.+0.0000000e+00j,
                0.+0.0000000e+00j]],
              dims=(2, 2))
```

Whereas the circuit

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.h(0)
circ.h(0)
circ.h(0)
circ.h(0)
circ.i(1)
circ.i(1)
circ.i(1)
circ.i(1)
circ.save_density_matrix()
print(circ)
```

Gives the correct output of

```
DensityMatrix([[0.5+0.000000e+00j, 0. -6.123234e-17j, 0. +0.000000e+00j,
                0. +0.000000e+00j],
               [0. +6.123234e-17j, 0. +0.000000e+00j, 0. +0.000000e+00j,
                0. +0.000000e+00j],
               [0. +0.000000e+00j, 0. +0.000000e+00j, 0.5+0.000000e+00j,
                0. -6.123234e-17j],
               [0. +0.000000e+00j, 0. +0.000000e+00j, 0. +6.123234e-17j,
                0. +0.000000e+00j]],
              dims=(2, 2))
```

So either there's some configuration option I'm missing from the documentation or I'll need to write a method to manually insert identity gates into my circuits. What's the best way forward?